# How to set correct permission for a created tmp folder in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, file-permissions

This is basicly my Dockerfile to build a nestJS application. As you can see I created a temp folder.

The app is going to create some files in this folder. But this is failing with a "Permission denied" error.

Running `whoami` gives me `nestjs`.

`ls -la` shows me `drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Sep 26 16:06 tmp` for the tmp folder.

Of course this must be a permission issue. But I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Is the order of `RUN` and `WORKDIR` correct?

```
FROM node:20.0.0-alpine3.17
RUN apk add dumb-init

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/tmp
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nestjs -u 1001

COPY --from=deps /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY ./ ./

USER nestjs

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/dumb-init", "--"]
CMD ["node", "main.js"]
```

Comment: I think you need to add `RUN chown -R nestjs /usr/src/app/tmp` after creating the directory and creating the user.

Comment: @HarilSatra Gives me the error `chown: unknown user nestjs`

Comment: @ user3142695 just to be clear you are running the `chown` command after `RUN adduser -S nestjs -u 1001`?